# Cannot Copy Paste PDF with Armenian Fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have built a php cms, I have pdf files with Armenian fonts, I try to copy them to notepad or word to paste into one textarea and one tinemyce wysiwig, but the fonts being armenian fonts I cannot copy paste correctly

I tried to search here by uploading to google drive and opening, even there it is presenting the same result

Many Thanks

Comment: what does "cannot copy paste correcty" mean? You can't copy the text from the pdf at all? Or you can't paste into your form at all? or they don't paste correctly? Or they crash your computer, kick your dog, and insult your mother?

Comment: it becomes strange text corrupted garbage

Comment: something like:

77-ð¸ î²ðÆ, ÂÆô 276 ¥19421¤ ¥4 ¿ç¤ ¶ÆÜª 1000 È.à.àôð´²Â, 19 ¸ºÎîºØ´ºð 2014 
²Ð²´ºÎâàôÂº²Ü ¼úð²ÎòàÔ äºîàôÂÆôÜ 
È»éÝ³ÛÇÝ Ô³ñ³µ³ÕÇ Ð³Ýñ³å»ïáõÃ»³Ý ³ñï³ùÇÝ ·áñÍáó Ý³Ë³ñ³ñáõÃÇõÝÁ Û³Ûï³ -
ñ³ñ»ó« Ã¿ ²ïñå¿Û×³ÝÇ Ù¿ç ÏÁ Ï³ñÍ»Ý« áñ Ñ³ÛÏ³Ï³Ý ÏáÕÙ»ñáõ Ñ³ëó¿ÇÝ Ù»Õ³¹ñ³ÝùÝ»ñáí 
Ñ³Ý¹¿ë ·³Éáí ÏñÝ³Ý Ó»ñµ³½³ïáõÇÉ µéÝáõÃÇõÝÝ»ñ ·áñÍ³¹ñáÕ »ñÏñÇ Ñ³Ùµ³õ¿Ý£ Ü³Ë³ -

Comment: So it's a charset issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: No Nothing PHP related, it is an adobe acrobat pdf file

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with php?

Comment: OK I will Remove PHP

Comment: Are you sure the PDF does contain the information required for text extraction?

Comment: Hello, yes , but as it is Armenian encoding it was damages when pasting on any format, form textarea, word, notepad, ..... and when saving online the same result,t he encoding was messy, so I used the website online which correctly interprets : http://unicodenow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website solves it:

```
             http://unicodenow.com/
```

This website you copy from pdf to the textareas, you have two choices, and from there to the website